# Black screen after new SATA card installation

Tags: boot, 18.04, sata, pcie, ahci

I'm at a real loss right now... I don't even know how to move forward with troubleshooting. I have an old sata card that I swear used to work, but when I boot with it plugged into any of my boards PCIE slots, the computer goes from BIOS screen to a black screen.

So I thought hey, I'll just pick up a different SATA card (I needed more ports anyway)... and I'm having the exact same problem. I've already removed `quiet` and `splash` from grub.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Mobo: ASUS Z87 Pro

Sata Card: https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B0177GBY0Y/ref=oh_aui_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Any thoughts on what I can try to move forward?

Comment: Try disabling boot from additional devices if it's enabled. Also do not connect drives to it in the first use.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried both of those unfortunately :(